# Save token as file

Tags: php, security, token, access-token

i would like to ask if is ok to save authorization token as a file in the specific folder. Or will be faster with every request connect to database and compare with token save in the table ? Thanks for answer

Comment: The performance impact of establishing a connection to the database is minimal if that's what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From the "what's faster" standpoint...*

Accessing, writing and reading files on the hard disk has its overhead and bears *- compared to accessing memory -* some performance loss. Databases *(again, typically)* also store their data on the hard disk, but also often keep data loaded in memory. That's because [accessing memory is **much faster** than accessing files on a hard drive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1371424/1285669).

So, if you're asking...

#### What's faster?

The answer would be *(most of the times)*: ***Database***.

#### And does it really matter?

Depends on your application.

- If you're having **five requests per second** reading your access tokens, then: **no, it doesn't matter**, and storing them on the disk is *- performance wise -* absolutely enough.
- If you need to read access tokens **(tens, hundreds of) thousands of times per second**, then using a database might be a slightly better *(faster)* option for you.